# How does relying party determine the user when resident keys are used?

Tags: webauthn, fido

When client-side discoverable resident keys are used with WebAuthN, it is not necessary for the relying party to first identify the user trying to sign in. How then does the RP know which user signed in? Does the RP just receive the AuthenticatorAssertionResponse and get the user.id from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of [`response.userHandle`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#iface-authenticatorassertionresponse) in an assertion response can be used to identify the user that's logging in - it will equal whatever was set to [`user.id`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#dom-publickeycredentialuserentity-id) in the `PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions` that were passed to `navigator.credentials.create()`.

`userHandle` *is* a potentially undefined value, but when resident keys are required during attestation then the authenticator *must* remember the user ID - [see Step 7.4 of the `authenticatorMakeCredential` operation](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-op-make-cred) (the user handle is part of the key the authenticator uses in its internal credentials map to remember a discoverable credential for a given RP ID and user handle).

Comment: when I get the `userHandle` from `navigator.credentials.get()` it's encrypted, how do I decode it to get the username/user id?

Comment: You're getting back the bytes you specified as `user.id` in the options you passed into `navigator.credentials.create()`. Encode the bytes into whatever they were decoded from, probably "utf-8" if it was a typical username string.